# Third party libraries in CMake

Tags: build, makefile, cmake

I am using cmake for my project, but I have another library in a subdirectory ( say lib/ ) which uses a plain Makefile. How do I instruct CMake to run the Makefile in lib as part of the build process?

Comment: This Makefile is single or generated by cmake ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automate building of third party library using cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728216/how-to-automate-building-of-third-party-library-using-cmake)

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to use:

`execute_process ( COMMAND make WORKING_DIRECTORY ${project_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/lib )`

Answer (score 3):

If your /lib contains its own **CMakeLists.txt**, just use the **add_subdirectory** command:

```
add_subdirectory(/path/of/your/lib/that/contains/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Else

you have to use **exec_program** command:

```
exec_program(script.sh)
```

where *script.sh* is

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/of/your/lib/ && make
```

do not forget

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

In my opinion, the first solution is better !!!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but execute_process() has superseded it. I found the answer the next day.